# How to convert Anonymous Type to Strong Type from LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have written a LINQ query which returns a new type of class, becuse I have used GROUP BY. Therefore, I have created a new class to cast Anonymous type to Strong Type. Here is my LINQ...

```
var result = rpt
    .GroupBy(x => new
                  {
                      CreateTime = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedTime),
                      x.UserId,
                      x.ProjectId
                  })
    .Select(x => new
                 {
                     UserId = x.Key.UserId,
                     ProjectId = x.Key.ProjectId,
                     CreateTime = x.Key.CreateTime,
                     TotalMinutesSpent = x.Sum(z => z.MinutesSpent)
                 })
    .OfType<List<UserTransactionReport>>().ToList();
```

My newly created class is like below...

```
public class UserTransactionReport
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public int TotalMinutesSpent { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert this anonymous to strong?

Comment: Why don't you just create a `UserTransactionReport` immediately?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create strongly typed objects in the select:

```
List<UserTransactionReport> result = 
    ...
    .Select(x => new UserTransactionReport
    {
       UserId = x.Key.UserId,
       ProjectId = x.Key.ProjectId,
       CreateTime = x.Key.CreateTime,
       TotalMinutesSpent = x.Sum(z => z.MinutesSpent)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, in case I have single object ? MyObj = new { properties ...}; And I have class DayInfo with same properties, how can I cast single object ?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, why didn't need parenthesis after "new UserTransactionReport"  in Select clause ?

Comment: @Grace that’s called an object initializer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Thx for help. ^_^